# How to include an arbitrary markdown file as a documentation attribute?

Tags: rust, rustdoc

If the `readme` `Cargo.toml` key is set, doc.rs renders the README on the crate's index page. Is there a way to emulate this when running `cargo doc` locally?

If I add:

```rust
#![doc = r###"contents
of
README.md
here
"###]
```

as a literal, I get the behaviour I'm looking for, but inlining a copy of my whole README.md is pretty inconvenient for making updates.

I tried:

```rust
#![doc = include!("README.md")]
```

but this gives an error:

```
error: unexpected token: `include`
 --> src/lib.rs:3:10
  |
3 | #![doc = include!("README.md")]
  |          ^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 11):

### Update as of Rust 1.54.0:

```
#![doc = include_str!("path/to/docs.md")]
```

---

### Original answer:

There is an unstable feature, [`external-doc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features/external-doc.html), which enables this:

Example usage (nightly-only):

```rust
#![feature(external_doc)]

#![doc(include = "../README.md")]
```

Comment: `#[doc = include_str!("my_doc.md")` is the new way to do this in nightly via [#78837](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/78837)